# How to print a ReportViewer's report without showing a form

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

While I realize that I could just show the form off-screen and hide it, along with many other forms of WinForms hackish wizardry, I'd rather stick with the zen path and get this done right. I have a SSRS local report (so no server) that I want to give the user the option of either viewing or printing (in other words, I don't want to force them to view to print). Unfortunately, the ReportViewer control complains about its "state" when I try to print it either as a component I'm creating explicitly in my code (inside a using() block, of course) or if I try to instantiate my viewer form and just print without ever showing it.

Is there a means to do this that will sit well with me, or should I just show it off-screen and move on with my life?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have a sample that does this posted on my blog here: http://blogs.msdn.com/brianhartman/archive/2009/02/27/manually-printing-a-report.aspx

The LocalReport object can be instantiated independently of the ReportViewer control and used directly in the sample code attached to that blog post.  Or you can pass in ReportViewer.LocalReport even if you don't first display the report in the UI.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I'll take a look at this solution first thing at work tomorrow.

Comment: Excellent solution; worked perfectly! Congrats on getting your first SO points from a bounty question ;)

Comment: Legend. Saved me a ton of time :)

Comment: Finally, thank you...works perfectly.  So glad to not have to use Crystal

Comment: Unfortunately the Link no longer works :( @BrianHartman could you provide an updated link please?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out and see if it helps...http://scruffylookingcatherder.com/archive/2007/12/07/printing-reporting-services-2005-reports.aspx

A little explanation: It's using the SSRS web service to render the report to an EMF image then send the image to the printer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a local report using data from a DataSet from a SqlCe 3.5 database, so anything to do with SSRS itself is probably out of the question.

Comment: @Mozy the link that you provided is not working. 
The correct link is http://scruffylookingcatherder.com/post/2007/12/08/Printing-Reporting-Services-2005-Reports.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below link very useful for you
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f52d79d-5baf-4e84-97d5-7dbba6623b89/printing-without-the-reportviewer

Comment: Maybe you could add a description of the solution available in the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub btnReceipt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReceipt.Click


    My.Forms.FormA5.ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Dim cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select * from V_Sale where InvoiceNo=" & Me.txtInvoice.Text, cn)
    Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Load(dr)
    dr.Close()
    Dim rpt As New ReportViewer
    rpt.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    rpt.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("posds_receipt", dt))
    rpt.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "POSsystem.receipt.rdlc"
    rpt.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
    rpt.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage

    Dim printDialog1 As PrintDialog = New PrintDialog
    printDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    Dim result As DialogResult = printDialog1.ShowDialog
    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End If

End Sub
```