# direct print asp.net report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I'm using .rdlc report in my **web application**, exporting report to pdf & print it works great but now i wanted to print report automatically(i,e on click of print button.)

```
Is it possible to print rdlc report automatically?
```

Please help me,
& thank you.

Comment: You could put a control-less reportviewer in a new browser window and print the whole thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731049/how-to-print-a-reportviewers-report-without-showing-a-form

Comment: @sinni800:  
Sorry, i'm not getting, can you please elaborate means how to do?

Comment: As @AntonioBakula and I already hinted, how about you make a POPUP window in the browser, render the full report there, and use window.print(); in Javascript on this window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to print rdlc report automatically?

If you can render it on a page you can use javascript window.print(), that prints current window. So as sinni800 said render report on separate page.

<s>Something like this,</s>

on page with other content add this button :

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('/print-content.html','_blank');">print report</a>
```

First parameter of open window is page with your report viewer, and in that page you can start print on load event, like this :

```
<body id="top" onload="window.print();">
    rendered report here
</body>
```

But if you ask me better stick with your current solution.

You can save your report as PDF on disk, open it with Javscript and then print it, there is a example on Code Project for exactly your scenario as I understud you :

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/376300/Custom-Print-functionality-for-Microsoft-Report-Vi

Comment: Sorry & Ya it'll print whatever content in window but my reports width is more than window size so getting to print hided content is not possible using above code? am i right?

Comment: yes, that prints all window content, same thing if you as use on that window choose print in browser

Comment: Is there any other option to print all content in the ms report(rdlc)?

Comment: Sorry, i wanted direct printing option, & i have done export to pdf option button.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in when you open your rdlc report in Internet Explorer report must have a button that does that printing job.

Comment: Yes your right Alper, but I'm mainly concentrated to work in chrome or in Mozilla because of my application added css will not support properly in explore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Active-X enabled browsers (ex. IE) the following solution should work:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
     function PrintReport() { 
         var viewerReference = $find("ReportViewer1");

         var stillonLoadState = viewerReference.get_isLoading();

         if (!stillonLoadState ) { 
             var reportArea = viewerReference .get_reportAreaContentType(); 
             if (reportArea == Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportAreaContent.ReportPage) { 
                 $find("ReportViewer1").invokePrintDialog(); 
             } 
         } 
     } 
 </script>
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/selvar/archive/2011/04/09/invoking-the-print-dialog-for-report-viewer-2010-control-using-the-javascript-api.aspx

Kindlyy note that this solution will not work on browsers that doesn't support Active-X