# c# Winform: ReportViewer, print Directly to default printer

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, reportviewer

I am using VS2013 with C#, and I have a small problem with `ReportViewer`.
When I click on the print button a dialog box opens for tell me to choose a printer.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reic2.jpg)

The problem is I don't want to see this dialog box. I want to print directly to default printer.

I found this answer but not it's working for me?! [Change behaviour of Print button in ReportViewer C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188890/change-behaviour-of-print-button-in-reportviewer-c-sharp)

Comment: Why it doesn't work for you? What's the issue with that solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, to set default printer.

```
using System.Configuration;

System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings pagina = new    System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings(); 
            pagina.PrinterName=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["textBox_ImpNOMBRE"];//default printer name
//ADD OTHER CONFIGURATIONS SETTINGS
        reportViewer1.PrinterSettings = pagina;
```